# AngularJS: ng-src behavior on non-standard attributes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm integrating a media player in my app using the "[Video For Everybody](http://v4e.thewikies.com/)" generator. As the player features a fallback to flash if the browser doesn't support HTML5 `video` and `audio` I have to build an `object` element with `param` attributes with the video and placeholder (image) source.

As expected I run into the classical problem of expressions not being resolved in time, my browser sends requests to `my.media.com/{{video.src}}` rather then `my.media.com/somevideo.mp4`

Unfortunately there are several attributes (`poster, flashvars, placeholder` to name a few) where I face the same problem. How would I go about creating the same behavior as the ng-src or ng-href directives? I tried looking for the relevant source code, but I haven't found it. Here is a snippet which showcases the problematic HTML,

```
<video controls="controls" poster="{{mediaModel.mediaFile2}}" width="300" height="150">
<source ng-src="{{mediaModel.mediaFile}}" type="{{mediaModel.contentType}}" />
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" width="300" height="150">
    <param name="movie" value="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="flashVars" value="{{'controllerbar=over&amp;image=' + media.mediaFile2 + '&amp;file=' + mediaModel.mediaFile}}" />
    <img ng-src="{{mediaModel.mediaFile2}}" width="300" height="150" title="{{mediaModel.uploadedTime}}" />
</object>
```

Comment: Can you share some of your approaches that are not working?

Comment: At this point I'm more or less stumbling in the dark trying to figure out if it is at all possible to apply a custom attribute, so I don't think any of the code I have at the moment will be constructive to the question. I will of course update as soon as I feel I have something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finding the source of build-in directive is made easy on the official API documentation. In this case go to the documentation of [ngSrc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSrc) , at the top of the page you will see two buttons, "Improve this doc" and "View source", click on "View source" and it will automatically take you to the correct source file where the directive is defined. This works across all build-in directive, very handy!

Below I'm pasting the code for ngSrc, which interestingly enough does not look complicated at all, the crucial line seems to be `priority: 99`, based on the comment next to it means that directives with priority of 99 will run **after** attributes have been interpolated.

```
// ng-src, ng-srcset, ng-href are interpolated
forEach(['src', 'srcset', 'href'], function(attrName) {
  var normalized = directiveNormalize('ng-' + attrName);
  ngAttributeAliasDirectives[normalized] = function() {
    return {
      priority: 99, // it needs to run after the attributes are interpolated
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        attr.$observe(normalized, function(value) {
          if (!value)
             return;

          attr.$set(attrName, value);

          // on IE, if "ng:src" directive declaration is used and "src" attribute doesn't exist
          // then calling element.setAttribute('src', 'foo') doesn't do anything, so we need
          // to set the property as well to achieve the desired effect.
          // we use attr[attrName] value since $set can sanitize the url.
          if (msie) element.prop(attrName, attr[attrName]);
        });
      }
    };
  };
});
```

Given the above it should be trivial to implement your own directive.

Comment: Great, thank you so much. Can't believe I've spent so much time in the Angular docs and overlooked that simple, but very practical feature. Just FYI: I'll hold out on accepting / rewarding bounty for a little while in case more answers pop up.

Comment: @KGChristensen NP glad I could help.

Answer (score 48):

You can now use `ng-attr-poster`, or more generally: `ng-attr-whatever`.

Answer (score 1):

So the most generic, maintainable, configurable and reusable solution is to create a custom directive that will handle it for you.

Look at this [-->PLNKR<--](http://plnkr.co/edit/y6wnaV5A1B5IfjWaXUhV?p=preview) there is practically all you need there. You have just to weak it a little bit.

How it works: to the directive you pass the configuration object (if you need more objects just create additional attributes). The element can be in two states: ready or not. And `$scope.isReady` just states if all the ingredients have been collected. If so `ngSwitch` loads the videoPlayer template and since all the information is there no unwanted requests are sent.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, though having a fixed timeout isn't really user friendly or a viable option here. I managed to create my own implementation of the ngSrc directive using $observe to watch for expression resolvement.

Comment: @KGChristensen you probably did not understand the code. Using `$timeout` was just to demonstrate that this approach **does work** and it was used in the controller and not in the directive itself. Directive waits for the scope to be populate, checks if all data are set properly and only than loads the template. How you populate the scope is **totally irrelevant**: I used `$timeout` as it was easiest. If you have all relevant information already there when controller is initialized the directive will work as well.

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that - had another glance at it now, was a bit quick last time around. Although I can see that this approach works it feels a bit cumbersome: Not including the template before the data is ready doesn't feel like playing on the strengths of the directive approach (especially compared to the ngSrc approach).

Comment: @KGChristensen May I ask you what exactly wrong with this approach?? You just pass one configuration object here and no need to manually set each individual attribute -- do you think it is worse then setting manually each ngSrc? (how possible?)

Comment: @KGChristensen If you were worrying about downloading the template itself -- cannot figure out what else could be the reason of your concerns -- AngularJS has in-built [`$templateCache`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$templateCache).

Comment: No, the template isn't a big problem due to the templateCache as you mention. What bothers me is that I don't like putting logic in the HTML/template, if possible I always put all directive logic in the deceleration (JS). On a general level I do agree that having one object rather then several attributes would be preferable, but due to reuse on other element types that isn't an option here (I do realize that I don't mention that in the original question, so sorry about the confusion).

Comment: @KGChristensen no problem with confusion. I am still curious what **logic** was put in html/template -- do you mean rather standard usage of `ng-switch`, which actually can be easily avoided altogether? Earlier you wrote: *Not including the template before the data is ready doesn't feel like playing on the strengths of the directive approach* -- it does not sound at all like: *I don't like putting logic in the HTML/template*. Moreover: why using the directive is impossible -- I am really curious, as can hardly imagine such a scenario...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with the `poster` attribute on a `video` tag. If you apply `ng-cloak` to elements that have `src`-like attributes, they won't try to load anything until they become visible when the cloak is removed.